# ListView does not receive click events

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

My scenario is the following:
- the application uses the actionbar configured to display tabs.
- one tab displays a layout containing multiple FrameLayouts that are dynamically replaced with fragments. Some of them can have ListViews. The example here is simplified and has only one fragment directly added in the xml layout.
- the first time the tab is opened everything works fine
- switching to another tab and back will draw the ListViews, allow scrolling but no click events. 
If I add other controls, like a button under the list they will work as expected. Furthermore, after using those controls the list will also start to get click events.
This is reproducible only when the actionbar buttons open a fragment that displays other fragments. If they open the list fragment everything works as expected.
The important code is:
Tab listener from Dev Guide:

```
public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {         
        if (mFragment == null) {               
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {             
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {              
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {           
    }
}
```

onCreateView method from the fragment opened from the actionbar:

```
View view = null;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
    }
    return view;
}
```

The tab layout, simplified here to display only a fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/runModesListFragment"
        android:name="tab.fail.TabFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

And, finally, the list

```
public class TabFragment extends ListFragment {
    String[] listContent = {
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16",
        "17"
    };

    View view = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

When the tab is selected again onCreateView and onActivityCreated don't get any call. This is the only difference I found compared to the case when the actionbar buttons open the list. Still, I don't have any idea why this matters nor how to fix it.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a workaround. Not nice and doesn't explain why only selection in ListView wasn't working while scroll and other views were fine but it does the job. Because onCreateView and onActivityCreated weren't called in this case I forced the framework to do it using attach/detach on the fragment. There isn't any noticeable performance hit but I'm convinced a better solution exists.

For reference, the code is:

```
    Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tabFragment);
    if (frag == null) {
        frag = new TabFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.tabFragment, frag);
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frag);
        ft.attach(frag);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

I shall mark this as accepted because there was no other idea posted.